# How can I set no auto increment in migration laravel 5.3?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, migration, laravel-5.3

My code migration is like this :

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('satkers', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        ...
    });
}
```

I run `php artisan migrate`. Then, I see in database administrator. It's like this : [image]

I do not want it to be auto incremented, so how can i do it through migration file.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set it as [`integer()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/migrations#columns) in migration and set primary key with [`primary()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/migrations#indexes):

```
$table->integer('id')->unsigned();
$table->primary('id');
```

Another way is to [define primary key in Eloquent model](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions):

> Eloquent will also assume that each table has a primary key column named id. You may define a $primaryKey property to override this convention.
>
> In addition, Eloquent assumes that the primary key is an incrementing integer value, which means that by default the primary key will be cast to an int automatically. If you wish to use a non-incrementing or a non-numeric primary key you must set the public $incrementing property on your model to false.

Answer (score 0):

if you want id but not auto increment then you have to use

```
$table->integer('id')->unsigned();
```

If `id` field is not required then remove  `$table->increments('id');` from the migration.

Comment: OP wants not nullable and unsigned, so you should remove `->nullable()` and add `->unsigned()`.

Answer (score -1):

By default when you create a migration file it will assume that there will be a auto incremented id in the table, but in case you don't  want it .
change it to this

```
$table->integer('id')->unsigned();
$table->primary('id');
```

save your migation file.
rollback your  migration through php artisan.
and then run php migrate command.